# Django: how to submit form whes user click radiobutton

Tags: django, forms

How to add:

```
onclick="this.form.submit();"
```

in my radiobutton form? I would like to post my form when user click to the radiobutton.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.news = kwargs.pop('news')
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    choices = ([ ("%s" % a.id, "%s" % a.text)  for a in  self.news])
    self.fields['new'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

I would like to have this result in template:

```
<input type="radio" id="new" name="new" value="new"  onclick="this.form.submit();">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
self.fields['new'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'onclick': 'this.form.submit();'}))
```

while it's not the best idea to place template logic in your .py files.

Answer (score 1):

How do you generate your form in a template?
If you use {{ form.as_p }} than consider rendering your custom form like described in: [Django's Custom Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template)